# How to capture user's typed URL after opening a DB in xpages

Tags: url, xpages

I've tried various URL options to try and capture the original URL the user typed or linked to after a database opens.  This is what I'm trying to do.  I have a domain and I need to allow the individual users to type the domain and their user ID so the initial DB can redirect them to their own personal databases which will make them login to that database.  Example: a user types: www.mydomain.com/userid.  In the database opened for mydomain.com, I need to capture "userid" and redirect to their DB.  These users will be authenticated and their databases don't allow anonymous access so it forces them to login at that point.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect rules at the server level. More info in admin help or here http://www.pmooney.net/2010/12/creating-a-url-redirection-for-a-domino-web-server/

I recommend to insert something before "userid", for example `www.mydomain.com/user/userid`.

If that "user" part of the url redirects to XPage, you can configure that redirect to pass anything behind "user/" part of the URL as parameter, for example `?userid=...`. Then use `context.getUrl()` method to read it and handle accordingly. More info here http://xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet2.nsf/url.xsp

Comment: Very good information, however, I am redirecting each user to a different database, not a link within the domain itself.  I have the front end domain database which is a website with my personally registered users.  I would like to capture the user's ID appended to that domain website and within the front end database, look up their database path, and redirect it there.  I may have thousands of users, maybe tens of thousands if I market this right.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's the point of the "handle" part - make single XPage that will lookup database/url from your directory and redirect there. Domino will redirect all the /user/ request to that page.

Comment: I tried doing that but in the onload or beforepageload event, when I get the current url, it's already changed to open the page that I specified in the database properties.  The actual URL that the user typed in with their userID is lost.  I tried getting prev history but it's not there.

Comment: Please, put every detail about your problem to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible with a custom REST servlet, but that is a more advanced option requiring an OSGi plugin coded with Java. There are a variety of blog posts covering approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a database with a url that all users point to like http://www.me.com/redirect.nsf/open.xsp/userid (you could setup a nice url with a redirect). Then the open.xsp parses the url and figures out where to send the user to their personal database/url and if you need the user id, adds that as a parameter and uses the context.redirecttopage method.